# Opscenter 5.0: User management query

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, cassandra, opscenter

I've installed the free tarball version of opscenter and am having problems with the user management aspect of it. I have authentication enabled via:

> [authentication]
>   enabled = true

...and can log in as the admin user. However, the rest of the user management functions are inaccessible. The documentation (http://www.datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/5.0/opsc/configure/opscManageUsers.html) explains how to enable authentication and then manage users/roles quite clearly. However, the menu option to do this is greyed out.

Can someone explain what I need to do to enable this function? In order to use opscenter we will need access control working.

Answer (score 4):

As per [documentation](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/5.0/opsc/configure/opscAboutAccessRoles_c.html), fine-grained permissions are available only if you’re managing a DSE cluster.

> OpsCenter can be configured to require users to login. DataStax Enterprise customers have the ability to define custom, fine-grained access roles for these users. If you are using DataStax Community, all users that login to OpsCenter will have admin rights.